# Shell script to read a file

Tags: bash, shell, sh, iptables

I have written a shell script to read a file which consists of IP addresses and then block them with the help of iptables. It works fine, But when I run the script for second time, it writes the rule again (duplicated). I want it to check if IP is already blocked then ignore it otherwise block. here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
ipadds="/home/asad/Downloads/blacklist"
dropit=$(grep -Ev "^#" $ipadds)
for i in $dropit; do
 iptables -A INPUT -s $i -j DROP
 iptables -A FORWARD -s $i -j DROP
done
```

Output after first time script run:

```
root@ubuntu:/home/asad/Downloads# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  192.168.248.2        anywhere
DROP       all  --  192.168.232.20       anywhere
DROP       all  --  192.168.232.5        anywhere
DROP       all  --  192.168.232.190      anywhere
Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  192.168.248.2        anywhere
DROP       all  --  192.168.232.20       anywhere
DROP       all  --  192.168.232.5        anywhere
DROP       all  --  192.168.232.190      anywhere
Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Output after second time script run:

```
root@ubuntu:/home/asad/Downloads# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  192.168.248.2        anywhere
DROP       all  --  192.168.232.20       anywhere
DROP       all  --  192.168.232.5        anywhere
DROP       all  --  192.168.232.190      anywhere
DROP       all  --  192.168.248.2        anywhere
DROP       all  --  192.168.232.20       anywhere
DROP       all  --  192.168.232.5        anywhere
DROP       all  --  192.168.232.190      anywhere
Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  192.168.248.2        anywhere
DROP       all  --  192.168.232.20       anywhere
DROP       all  --  192.168.232.5        anywhere
DROP       all  --  192.168.232.190      anywhere
DROP       all  --  192.168.248.2        anywhere
DROP       all  --  192.168.232.20       anywhere
DROP       all  --  192.168.232.5        anywhere
DROP       all  --  192.168.232.190      anywhere
Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

how to avoid this duplication? any help please

Comment: Do not use `for` for looping command output, use process-substitution with `while`

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: Realized it just it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Your intended code does not work that way. You should have needed an array for storing the command output. Your current syntax allows shell to do word splitting to treat a single space separated line to multiple entries

Comment: Frankly, I'd strongly suggest using a framework that can already do this for you -- such as [Shorewall](http://shorewall.org/) -- rather than reinventing the wheel yourself.

Comment: I definitely agree with @CharlesDuffy. [Fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/) also comes to mind. YMMV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
ipadds=/home/asad/Downloads/blacklist
grep -v "^#" $ipadds | while read i; do
 if ! iptables -nL INPUT | grep -Fq "$i" ; then
   iptables -A INPUT -s "$i" -j DROP
   iptables -A FORWARD -s "$i" -j DROP
 fi
done
```

Or (maybe this makes little difference to you)

```
#!/bin/bash
ipadds=/home/asad/Downloads/blacklist
while read i; do
 if ! iptables -nL INPUT | grep -Fq "$i" ; then
   iptables -A INPUT -s "$i" -j DROP
   iptables -A FORWARD -s "$i" -j DROP
 fi
done < <(grep -v "^#" $ipadds)
```

Please note that the `-E` flag for `grep` is not needed in this case. It is crucial to pass the `-n` flag to `iptables -L` in order to get IP’s and not hostnames; it also improves performance.  I assume that your INPUT and FORWARD chains are kept in sync, therefore I only check one of them. If this is not the case, one should check both, of course.

The exact semantics of the above script is: “don’t insert a new candidate IP if it’s already mentioned anywhere in the INPUT chain” which is a little different from “... if it’s already blocked”. A more efficient solution based on `iptables -C` would look for a particular rule, but not for other mentions of the IP in the chain. I can think of scenarios where either approach is preferable.

If you have lots of IP’s in your iptables chains, scanning a whole chain to check if a candidate IP is already there might be inefficient. If this becomes a problem, there are various ways to build an external index for more efficient IP lookups, but OTOH the whole system would become more difficult to maintain, so I’d experiment without external indexes for a start.

Comment: Good points! Would be good if you add double-quotes around `$i` as `"$i"` to be more roubust

Comment: @Inian `$i` is legal if and only if it contains a valid IP address, i.e. dots and digits (in an ipV4 environment), and putting it in quotes would only preserve illegal characters. To increase robustness, one should parse it accordingly, and _that_ would be inefficient. I cannot think of a case where `$ip` would fail and `"$ip"` succeed.

Comment: Quoting doesn't hurt. Especially if `IFS` contains a period or digits. Really, never make assumptions. Just quote every single expansion. A bigger problem, though, is that the periods will be interpreted as “match any single character”. Another problem is that the regex isn't anchored.

Comment: Still lacks quotes, and still isn't anchored.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Agreed about the incorrect interpretation of dots: I edited the answer adding `-F` to `grep`; it’s also more efficient. Not being anchored is a *feature*, clearly stated in the answer. Quotes are not needed: show me a case where they would save this script from incorrect input. Don’t apply principles blindly.

Comment: As I said, it will break if `IFS` contains a period or a digit. You'll argue it's unlikely, I'll argue that it doesn't hurt to quote anyway: the more protections we use, the more robust the script is. Especially for a script meant to be run as root.

Comment: Unquoted variables and quoted variables don't have the same _semantic_ anyway (maybe that semantic is _ad hoc,_ but it's here anyway): unquoted assume that word splitting and pathname expansion will occur; quoted assume verbatim data. Here you're in the latter case. So use quotes. Also in the filename. (The funny thing is that you used quotes in the variable assignment, where it's not needed.)

Comment: `IFS=. read i <<<"1.2.3.4"; echo $i` leaves the dots in place, since I’m reading only one variable.

Comment: @Dario: no, that's because you haven't assigned `IFS` globally. In your snippet, `IFS` is only an environment variable to `read`, so its value is restored and then `echo $i` is executed. Try this instead: `i="1.2.3.4" IFS=.; echo $i`. Surprise.

Comment: @RAZHamraz, ...don't run it continuously in the background; that's needlessly wasteful, when those invocations will only do anything useful if the blacklist has been updated. Instead, use a program like [`incron`](http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=incron&page=about&lang=en) to run it once every time the `blacklist` file changes, and hook it into your distro's network scripts to run it once (only once!) after an interface has been started/restarted/etc.

Comment: Yes, as @CharlesDuffy says, this script should be run only when needed. However, see also the comments to the question. You should use an already-established framework for continuous use.

Comment: @RAZHamraz, probably you need to implement locking to avoid race conditions. We *did* tell you to use something else written by people who've actually been working in this problem space for a while, right?

Comment: @RAZHamraz, what I mean about "locking" -- think about what happens if you have two file operations so close to each other that you have multiple copies of your blacklist script invoked (effectively) at the same time, starting one before the other is done.

Comment: @RAZHamraz, ...again: Don't reinvent wheels. There's a lot wrong with your code -- just to throw something out, if you try to block `1.2.3.4`, it'll think it's already done if you happen to be blocking `1.2.3.40` -- and it's extremely inefficient to boot (using a separate `grep` per-line rather than an efficient set-operation tool such as `comm` means it'll get slower as more lines are added at a much higher rate than it needs to). Use something that's already battle-tested in production by a lot of people for a lot of years, and you'll gain the benefit of their collective experience.

Comment: @Charles Duffy you are right, but I don't know the reason why this happening while there is not a single error and not two files.

Comment: @RAZHamraz, ...you don't need to have two files to have two *instances* of the same script running at the same time. The details of how that's likely to happen depend on access patterns by your writers, and exactly how you have incron configured -- but even if you don't have an explicit scenario that makes it *likely* to happen, it's always *possible* unless you've taken active precautions (ie. locking) against it.

Answer (score 0):

you could try

```
#!/bin/bash

ipadds="/home/asad/Downloads/blacklist"

while IFS='' read -r 
do 
    # check if the rule already exists - if not add it - and 
    # silently ignore warnings for rules that dont exist
    if ! iptables -C INPUT -s "$REPLY" -j DROP 2> /dev/null
    then 
        iptables -A INPUT -s "$REPLY" -j DROP
    fi

    if ! iptables -C FORWARD -s "$REPLY" -j DROP 2> /dev/null
    then 
        iptables -A FORWARD -s "$REPLY" -j DROP
    fi
# Please note proper syntax for process substitution
done < <(grep -Ev "^#" $ipadds)
```

Comment: Very good answer (I edited it because it lacked a necessary `<`-sign).

Comment: @Inian it works but got many warnings:
"iptables v1.6.0: host/network `' not found". any way thank you for your attention.